# how to skip the duplicate rows while reading csv file?

Tags: java, json, couchdb

I need to skip the duplicates in the csv file and need to insert original values into my couch database.
Here is my code.

```
public class Json {
    public List<User> jsonConvert()
                throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        File input = new File("C:\\Users\\SwedhaS\\Documents\\SametimeFileTransfers\\newPIRs.csv");      

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",");

        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));) {
            List<User> users = in 
                .lines()
                .skip(1)
                .<User>map(line -> {
                    String[]x = new String[6];
                    x = pattern.split(line);
                    return new User(x);
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
            mapper.writeValue(System.out, users);

            return users;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming `equals` and `hashcode` are properly implemented in `User`,  try replacing your `List` with a `Set` (cf. `Collectors.toSet()` ).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to remove the duplicates from the `users` List, right?

For doing so, and if you also want to preserve the order, you can use a HashSet, which automatically removes duplicates:

```
Set<String> usersSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(users);
```